# What make my file become read only when I use open()

Tags: filesystem, c++

We created one applications using below source code(C++):

```
int_t fd = open( "test.conf",O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR );
```

From the beginning, test.conf was OK, it is a read-write file. One day, it became a read-only file suddenly.

```
-r--------    1 symgr   platform        19 Oct  8 08:42 test.conf
-rw-r-----    1 dvmgr   platform        36 Oct 22  2019 volume.conf
```

What is impacted to an attribute of test.conf?

References:
https://linux.die.net/man/3/open
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html